# Counting ways to climb up the stairs

Tags: python, recursion

"You are climbing a staircase. It takes n steps to reach the top.
Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?"

I saw this question on leetcode and I was trying to work it out using recursive way. I am not sure if this is the proper approach but I still gave it a try. Can someone please help me and tell me if this is even a right approach?

```
WAYS = 0   # global variable?

def climb_stairs(n):
    if n == 0:
        WAYS += 1
        return
    else:
        climb_stairs(n-1)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            climb_stairs(n-2)
    return WAYS
```

Comment: if you modify a global variable then you need to use `GLOBAL WAYS` inside your function. Also if the variable is global it doesn't make much sense to return it. You can avoid using a global variable by passing it as a parameter. Then your `if n % 2 == 0` part of the code is unreachable

Comment: The first return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from optimal solution - the complexity will be O(2^n). To achieve an optimal programatic solution you should use DP / memoization:

```py
def climb_stairs_updated(n):
    climb_stairs_updated.counter += 1
    if n <= 2:
        memoization[n] = n
        return n
    if n in memoization:
        return memoization[n]
    else:
        result = climb_stairs_updated(n-1) + climb_stairs_updated(n-2)
        memoization[n] = result
        return result
    
memoization = {}
climb_stairs_updated.counter = 0
climb_stairs_updated(5)
```

The counter in the function counts the call for evaluation purposes - the solution is in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you simply need to use:

```
def climb_stairs(n): # n > 0
    if n <= 2:
        return n # if 2 steps, 2 ways (1 or 2), else only 1
    else:
        # if we chose 1, then there are n-1 steps left
        # if we chose 2, then there are n-2 steps left
        return climb_stairs(n-1)+climb_stairs(n-2)

climb_stairs(2)
# 2 (1+1 or 2)

climb_stairs(5)
# 8 (1+1+1+1+1, 2+1+1+1, 1+2+1+1, 1+1+2+1, 1+1+1+2, 2+2+1, 2+1+2, 1+2+2)
```

##### complexity

I assumed the question was before all a coding training. If you want to improve efficiency you can use a cache, wuch as [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) (or [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) for python ≥ 3.9):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def climb_stairs(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return n # if 2 steps, 2 ways (1 or 2), else only 1
    else:
        return climb_stairs(n-1)+climb_stairs(n-2)
    
climb_stairs(40)
# 165580141
```

Comment: Neat! What do yo mean with 'else only 1' in your comment?

Comment: @Tobias if you have 2 steps left you can do 1+1 or 2, if you have 1 step left, you can only do 1. So for n<=2 then number of choices equals the number of steps (this wouldn't be true for more choices, e.g., 1/2/3)

Comment: ah thanks, I thought the `else` was referring to the else statement

Comment: Thank you. I'm like 2 weeks into studying coding. Is something like this what you learn in computer science curriculum or is it something intuitive that you need to have these skills in order to be successful in computer science?

Answer (score 0):

If you approach from top to bottom it will be easier. Imagine you have 5 stair cases:

If you are at the last staircase, it takes 1 step to reach top. that is default. If you are at the (n-1)th staircase in this case you are at 4th staircase, it would take 1 step to reach the top.

[image]

now you ask how many different ways you can reach the top from 3rd staircase. If take 1 step up, you get 4th and you already know from the 4th step it takes 1 step to reach the top. If you take 2 steps up, you reach the top and from top it takes 1 step to reach by default. So, you can see that from 3rd step, it takes 1+1 to reach the top. based on this logic:

```
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        one,two=1,1
        # since we initialized one,two, we have to compute only n-1 values. remember n-1 is not inclusive
        for i in range(n-1):
            one,two=two,one+two
        return two
```